# LINQ Grouping by custom type not working

Tags: c#, linq, linq-group

I have data I receive from a web service via `HTTPWebRequest`. After I parse it using `NewtonSoft.Deserialize` into a custom type (a simple class with public string properties), I want to manipulate this data using `LINQ` - more specifically, I want to group the data.

My problem is that the grouping works fine if I group by a single string property

```
from x in myList
group x by x.myStr into grp
select grp;
```

Since I want to group by more columns, I am returning a custom type with

```
new MyType { a = ..., b = ... }
```

The group is however not working. I thought the reason must be the compiler does not know how to compare these objects - so if this type implements `IEqualityComparer<MyType>` it will solve it.

But no, it is still not grouping accordingly, and it creates several keys with the exact same string values.

The custom type by which I am grouping is something like

```
public class MyType
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public string c;
}
```

Any ideas of what am I missing?

Here's a concrete example of the scenario described above:

```
//The type that models the data returned from the web service
public class MyClass
{
    public string a { get; set; }

    public string b { get; set; }

    public string c { get; set; }

    public DateTime d { get; set; }

    public DateTime e { get; set; }
}

// the type by which I want to group my data
public class MyGroup : IEquatable<MyGroup>, IEqualityComparer<MyGroup>
{
    public string f1 { get; set; }

    public DateTime d1 { get; set; }

    public DateTime d2 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyGroup other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.f1, other.f1) == 0;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyGroup x, MyGroup y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.f1, y.f1) == 0;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyGroup obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}    
    List<MyClass> l = new List<MyClass>();
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaa", b = "bbb", c = "ccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20081405", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaaa", b = "bbb", c = "ccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20090105", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140201", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aa", b = "bbbb", c = "cccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20081405", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140201", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaa", b = "bbbbb", c = "ccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20121111", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaaaa", b = "bbb", c = "ccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20081405", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaaa", b = "bbbbb", c = "ccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20121111", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140101", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaaa", b = "bbbb", c = "cccccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20081405", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140201", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaaaa", b = "bbb", c = "cccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20090105", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140301", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });
    l.Add(new MyClass { a = "aaa", b = "bbb", c = "cccc", d = DateTime.ParseExact("20081405", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture), e = DateTime.ParseExact("20140201", "yyyyddMM", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture) });

    //The following does not really group
    //IEnumerable<IGrouping<MyGroup, MyClass>> r = from x in l
    IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClass>> r = from x in l
                                                //group x by new MyGroup { f1 = x.a /*, d1 = x.d, d2 = x.e*/ } into grp
                                                orderby x.a
                                                group x by x.a into grp
                                                select grp;

    //foreach (IGrouping<MyGroup, MyClass> g in r)
    foreach (IGrouping<string, MyClass> g in r)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(g.Key.f1);

        Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
    }
```

Comment: override Equals and GetHashCode

Comment: How are you doing the grouping when you use `MyType`?

Comment: How are you implementing `IEqualityComparer`?  It's easy to get that wrong.

Comment: @Habib: As I wrote above, I did that, to no avail.

Comment: Please provide the query that is not working for you

Comment: @Veverke Clearly *you didn't do it right* then, so we need to see what your implementations of these methods are to tell you why it is not stating that equal objects are equal.

Comment: I added a concrete example, implementing both IEqualityComparer and IEquitable - it will still not group properly.

Comment: The reason it did not work was I was missing overrides for Equals and GetHashCode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought the reason must be the compiler does not know how to compare these objects - so if this type implements `IEqualityComparer<MyType>` it will solve it.

Actually, to use a custom "equality" check in Linq functions you need to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms131187(v=vs.100).aspx).  `IEquatable<T>` is used to compare an instance of an object with another object of the same type - while `IEqualityProvider<T>` is meant to be implemented by an external class to compare two arbitrary `T`s (and/or to have *multiple* methods of determining "equality").

Note that you should also implement `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` - `IEquatable<T>` just allows you to compare in a type-safe manner.

> Why the need for overriding `Object`'s `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

To ensure that *any* method (`Object.Equals(object)`, the static `Object.Equals(object, object`, etc.) used to compare two objects is consistent.  And any time you override `Equals`, you should also override `GetHashCode` to ensure that objects can be properly stored in a hash-based collection like a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`.

> What does it mean IEquitable only compares in a type-safe manner?

When using `IEquatable<T>`, the object you're comparing to is *guaranteed* to be a `T` (or a subtype of `T`), whereas with `Object.Equals`, you don't know the type of the other object and must check it's type first.

For example:

```
// IEquatable<T>.Equals()
public bool Equals(MyGroup other)
{
    return string.Compare(this.f1, other.f1) == 0;
}
```

versus

```
// Object.Equals()
public bool Equals(object other)
{
    // need to check the type of the passed in object
    MyGroup grp = other as MyGroup;

    // other is not a MyGroup
    if(grp == null return false);        

    return string.Compare(this.f1, grp.f1) == 0;

    // you could also use
    //    return this.Equals(grp);
    // as a shortcut to reuse the same "equality" logic
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution, D. Stanley. Could you clarify why the need for overriding Object's Equals and GetHashCode? What does it mean IEquitable<T> only compares in a type-safe manner? The fact that without the overrides, only with IEquitable's implementation it does not work - means I am working type-unsafe? Why? After all I am not working with anonymous types - on the contrary - I took the time to declare each and every type I am working with...

Comment: @Veverke Each time a new entry in `myList` is reached, we group by a `new MyType { a = ..., ... }`. Linq will have to decide if this `new MyType` is the "same" as an earlier encountered `MyType`. For that it uses the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to see if they are "the same". If you do not override the methods, a `new` instance of `MyType` is "not equal" to another instance, even if bot `a`, `b` and `c` look the same.

Comment: @Veverke I have added my answers to your follow-up questions.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen ok, but if you say "if you do not override the methods, a new instance of MyType is not equal to another instance..." - what is the purpose then of implementing IEquitable? I would think it was for this very reason...

Comment: `IEquatable.Equals` will be faster than `object.Equals` since it does not need to cast or box/unbox the inputs to determine equality. The output for IEquatable.Equals` and `object.Equals`  should be consistent.

Comment: So, summing up the lesson learned - every time we implement interfaces that generate implementations of Equals and/or GetHashCode - we are required to override both Object's static methods?

Comment: More accurately - if you implement `IEquatable<T>` you must also override `object.Equals(object)`.  If you override `object.Equals(object)` you must also override `object.GetHashCode()` (and vice-versa).  Implementing `IEquatable<T>` is optional but can improve performance. You can't override the static `Object.Equals(object, object)` method (but it calls `object.equals(object)` on the left instance).  `IEqualityComparer<T>` is designed to be implemented on a class ohter than `T` (think of it as an "alternate" method of defining equality).

Comment: @DStanley: I was building up on your answer till the point of "the static Object.Equals" - I don't see where/how Object is a static class. More importantly: based on what you write in the beginning - can I thus infer that it would suffice in this case to override Object.Equals (and in turn override GetHashCode as well) ? I mean, implementing IEquitable solely confers me performance enhacement? Or is it part of the requirement for grouping by custom types?

Comment: @Veverke `object` is not a static class but `object.Equals(object, object)` is a static method and thus can't be overridden.  `IEquatable` is not _required_ but is easier to code and avoids casting for reference types and boxing/unboxing for value types.

Answer (score 3):

> Any ideas of what am I missing?

Something like:

```
public class MyType : IEquatable<MyType>
{
  public string a;
  public string b;
  public string c;

  public bool Equals(MyType other)
  {
    if (other == null)
      return false;

    if (GetType() != other.GetType()) // can be omitted if you mark the CLASS as sealed
      return false;

    return a == other.a && b == other.b && c == other.c;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    return Equals(obj as MyType);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    int hash = 0;
    if (a != null)
      hash ^= a.GetHashCode();
    if (b != null)
      hash ^= b.GetHashCode();
    if (c != null)
      hash ^= c.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
  }
}
```

Addition: Note that `MyType` above is mutable, and the hash code changes if one of the fields `a`, `b` and `c` are re-assigned. That is problematic if the re-assignment happens while the instance is being held in a `Dictionary<MyType, whatever>`, `HashSet<MyType>` etc.

---

Alternatively, you could "group by" an anonymous type as suggested in DavidG's answer, or "group by" `Tuple.Create(.. , .. , ..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do your grouping using an anonymous type. The individual values themselves appear to be strings (i.e. simple types that already have built in comparers) so you don't need a custom type for anything other than the return. this way there is no need to worry about `IEqualityComparer`.

```
from x in myList
group x by new { x.myStr, x.otherStr, x.AnotherStr } into grp
select new MyTpe 
{
    a = grp.Key.myStr, 
    b = grp.Key.otherStr, 
    c = grp.Key.AnotherStr
};
```

Comment: For me it will be a considerable drawback not to have compile check/intelisense in further manipulations in the group results... so I'd rather define my grouping type.

Comment: What makes you think none of that is available?

Comment: oops, I misunderstood - I thought you were selecting from the anonymous type, not from MyType - meaning the resulting IEnumerable collection of IGrouping<> will have compile time check/intelisense. I thought you were returning an anonymous type.

Comment: Ah I see. Though selecting the anonymous type still gives you compile checks and intellisense. They are still real types, think of them as types that you don't know the name of.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the insights, David.