# GroupBy returns different results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<StatusType, Request>> group = requests.GroupBy(r=> r.StatusType );
```

The grouping function above works with when **requests** (`List<Requests>`) is from `EntityFramework/db`.
When changing the assignment of **requests** from **db direct**, to a **web service**,
the grouping isn't working as intended.

Digging a bit, I found that the **hash** or **equality** of the `StatusType`'s is different when coming from **db** vs **web** (found out thru this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24760630/8667400)).

From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24760843/8667400) of the post, I can bypass/(*resolve*?) the problem by overriding..

```
public class StatusType : IEquatable<int>
{   // omitted other crucial equality comparison components.
    // but for brevity..
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }
}
```

Although overriding `StatusType` somewhat resolves the issue,
I feel its quite risky as

1. I am not the author of the code base.
2. There are multiple references to `StatusType` increasing the potential
   of impending failure.

#### My question,

Is there a way to group by the `StatusTypeId` (**int**)

```
requests.groupBy(r=> r.StatusTypeId) // returns IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,Rquest>>
```

but get the `StatusType`?

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<StatusType,Rquest>>
```

Comment: What is your original problem? Sounds like you're going down the wrong path with this fix.

Comment: @CoryNelson, its grouping not working when porting my model source from direct db retreival to a web based service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define comparer for `StatusType`:

```
public class StatusTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<StatusType>
{
    public bool Equals(StatusType x, StatusType y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(StatusType obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Pass it to `GroupBy` method:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<StatusType, Request>> group = 
                    requests.GroupBy(r => r.StatusType, 
                                          new StatusTypeComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Backs has a much better answer than mine but I thought I'd post it anyway in the interests of diversity.

You might be able to get something like the functionality you're looking for by using multiple Linq queries. I don't know if there is an accessible implementation of `IGrouping` I can use, so I've gone with `Tuple<StatusType, List<Request>>` instead. It should have a similar effect. So, from your original query:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Request>> group = requests.GroupBy(r=> r.StatusTypeId );
```

You can add the following line:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<StatusType, List<Request>>> groupByStatusType = 
  group.Select(x => new Tuple<StatusType, List<Request>>(x.First().StatusType, 
                                                         x.ToList()));
```

Or, you can do it all on one line:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<StatusType, List<Request>>> group = 
  requests.GroupBy(r => r.StatusTypeId)
          .Select(x => new Tuple<StatusType, List<Request>>(x.First().StatusType, 
                                                            x.ToList()));
```

You can of course tweak the queries depending on what kind of output you're expecting, but this should at least get you started. Alternately, you could get a similar result by implementing a function that iterates through everything and "manually" creates an output.